# Angular 4 -> push to array

Tags: arrays, angular

Need assistance pushing new cards when the "Hit" button is selected to the **cards[]** array. I've tried a myriad of methods but can't seem to nail this simple issue. Assistance is greatly valued!

```
      @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
      })
      export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app';
      deck: any;
      cards = [];
      hand = 0;
      cardCount: number;

      constructor(private _data: DataService){
        console.log("Data Service ready to query api");
        this.cards = [];
      };


      newDeck(){
            this._data.newDeck().subscribe(res => this.deck = res.json());

      }

      deal(cardCount){

        this._data.deal(cardCount, this.deck.deck_id).subscribe(response => this.cards = response.json());
        if(this.cards) {
          this.cards.push(this.cards);
        }
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is wrong , because:

- When you receive response you reassign `response.json` to `this.cards`
- When your `deal` method gets called it simply subscribes, and then pushes `this.cards` array into itself if the condition `this.cards` is `true`.

```js
deal(cardCount)
    {
            this._data.deal(cardCount, this.deck.deck_id).subscribe(response => { 
                           const cards = response.json() 
                           if(cards) {
                               this.cards.push(cards);
                           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code inside subscribe, as it is asynchronous

```
deal(cardCount){
    this._data.deal(cardCount, this.deck.deck_id).subscribe(response => 
        if(response) {
            this.cards.push(response.json());
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey! I tried this as well but I receive error -> ERROR TypeError: _this.cards.push is not a function